# Deal with missing value errors in dataframe

Tags: r, database, dataframe, error-handling, missing-data

The database to which I am referring misses some data and as a consequence when I run this part of the code

```
for (i in 1:length(datemax)){
  
  for ( k in 1:length(strikemax)){
    
   chartmax[i,k] <- (dfmax[which(dfmax$Date == datemax[i] & dfmax$Strike == strikemax[k])][,5])
     
  }
}
```

I am obtaining the following error:

`Error in x[[jj]][iseq] <- vjj : replacement has length zero`

Indeed, the element that I am trying to add is "empty"

`Empty data.table (0 rows and 1 cols): iVol`

Thus, I am looking for a way to check if the value exists before doing the assignation to `chartmax[i,k]`

Ideally, if the value does not exist I would like to assign the value of the day before, that would be:

`dfmax[which(dfmax$Date == datemax[i-1] & dfmax$Strike == strikemax[k])][,5]`

I cannot give you the database as it is data sensitive... I would really appreciate help from you if capable!

Comment: Based on the error, I guess the condition in one of the iteration is not returning any TRUE

Answer (score 0):

This can be vectorized with `%in%` (a reproducible example would be easier to test)

```
i1 <- with(dfmax, Date %in% datemax & Strike %in% strikemax)
chartmax[i1,] <- dfmax[[5]][i1]
```

---

Regarding the OP's code issue, we need the lhs and rhs to satisfy the condition or use an `if/else` condition to only assign when the `length` of the index is 1 ('i1')

```
for (i in 1:length(datemax)){
  
  for ( k in 1:length(strikemax)){
    i1 <- which(dfmax$Date == datemax[i] & dfmax$Strike == strikemax[k])
    if(length(i1) == 1) {
      chartmax[i,k] <- (dfmax[w][,5])
      } else {
        chartmax[i,k] <- NA
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @ankur for the response! I tested this method and it does not suit as the length is always 1 (0 rows and 1 column). However, I went for a similar solution that is checking for the number of rows - when the element does not exist is 0, when it does it's 1. I then replaced the value with the mean and not with NA or the previous value as then it would have been hard to make a decent chart.

It's not the most beautiful and efficient way but it works!